# Hide JavaScript code from Internet Explorer and Firefox

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var imageID = 0;
    function changeimage(every_seconds) {

        //Change the image
        if (!imageID) {
            document.getElementById("myimage").src = "jesus.jpg";
            imageID++;
        } else { if(imageID==1) {
            document.getElementById("myimage").src="crucifixion.jpg";
            imageID++;
        } else { if(imageID==2) {
            document.getElementById("myimage").src="resurrection.jpg";
            imageID++;
        } else { if(imageID==3) {
            document.getElementById("myimage").src="trinity.jpg";
            imageID=0;
        }}}}

        //Call the same function again for x number of seconds
        setTimeout("changeimage("+every_seconds+")",((every_seconds)*1000));
    }

    var k=0;

    <!--[if gte IE, FF]><!-->

    var k=1;

    <!--><![endif]-->

    function mytext1() {
        if (k==1) {
            document.getElementById("mylink").href="king.html";
            document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML="THE KING OF KINGS";
        } else { if(k==2) {
            document.getElementById("mylink").href="crucifixion.html";
            document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML="HE WAS PUNISHED FOR OUR SINS";
        } else{ if(k==3) {
            document.getElementById("mylink").href="resurrection.html";
            document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML="HE WON DEATH";
        } else { if(k==4) {
            document.getElementById("mylink").href="trinity.html";
            document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML="THE HOLY TRINITY";
            k=0;
        }}}}
        k++;
    }
</script>
```

For the program to work in all browsers, the k must be equal to 1 in Chrome and 0 in Internet Explorer and Firefox.

How do I hide `K=1;` from Internet Explorer and Firefox?

Comment: *"For the program to work in all browsers the k must be equal to 1 in Chrome and 0 in Internet Explorer and Firefox."* Why? What makes you think that?

Comment: Separately: You may find this useful: [The `switch` statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.11).

Comment: **And**: How are `changeimage` and `mytext1` called?

Comment: }else{if{ ? Sorry, what language is it again ?

Comment: Ho i get it now, }}}}}}}}}... at the bottom, totally readable...
You might want to learn using switch()

Comment: Moved from LISP to JS?

Comment: } else if (x == y) { would be a good start too. Oh, conditional comments <!--[if gte IE, FF]><!--> in JS ?? Btw only ie lt 10 supports them so FF in there is made up syntax.

Answer (score 0):

To detect Internet Explorer, you can use `navigator.appName` property:

```
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') k = 1;
```

To detect Chrome, you can use

```
if (window.chrome) k = 0;
```

To detect Firefox, I suggest to use `navigator.userAgent` property

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) k = 1;
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)